# Como Comparar Datas

Tags: c#

Tenho este código para fazer um save dos dados introduzidos, Dia, DiaInicio e DiaFim.

```
protected void btnSavePontuacao_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        decimal id_TipoDia = 0;
        string Dia = txtDay.Text;
        string DiaInicio = txtStartDate.Text;
        string DiaFim = txtEndDate.Text;
        DateTime DtInicio, DtFim;


        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Dia) && DateTime.TryParse(DiaInicio, out DtInicio))
        {
            bool result = false;
            DateTime? DtFimNullable;

            if (DateTime.TryParse(DiaFim, out DtFim))
            {
                DtFimNullable = DtFim;
            }
            else
            {
                DtFimNullable = null;
            }

            if (CheckIfRatesRangeValuesAreValid(id_TipoDia, DtInicio, DtFimNullable))
            {
                if (id_TipoDia > 0)
                {
                    result = FlowCreditTaxasProdutoExtensaoPrazoProviderManager.Provider.UpdateProdutoAmortizacaoCreditoDias(id, Dia, DiaInicio, DtFimNullable);
                }
                else
                {
                    result = FlowCreditTaxasProdutoExtensaoPrazoProviderManager.Provider.InsertProdutoAmortizacaoCreditoDias(Dia, DiaInicio, DiaFim);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                result = false;
            }

            if (result)
            {
                ShowMessageJS("sucesso");
            }
            else
            {
                ShowMessageJS("fail");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ShowMessageJS("");
        }
    }
```

No

> CheckIfRatesRangeValuesAreValid

gostaria de saber como posso fazer uma validação das datas, ou seja se a data de fim for inferior a data de inicio

Comment: Esse código nem compila. Não existe conversão implícita de `DateTime` pra `int`.

Comment: Certo! Agora eu gostava era de saber se dá e como converto isso?

Comment: A sua publicação não faz o mínimo de sentido se comparado com a sua dúvida real. Além disso, não tem como saber o que você quer fazer. Converter uma data para inteiro? De que forma? Qual informação da data você pretende usar para colocar num número?

Comment: Tudo editado! Pode ser que assim de para entender melhor. :)

Comment: Não entendo qual a relação deste código com o anterior e, pra ser sincero, ainda não dá pra entender nada.

Comment: Este código é a criação de botão salvar os dados introduzidos, certo? agora a questão é eu necessito de validar se a data esta correta ou nao. através do CheckIfRatesRangeValuesAreValid. o objetivo é fazer o insert na bd

Comment: @jbueno, esta resolvido pode-se fechar. Obrigado pela tentativa de ajuda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o método Método Compare do DateTime https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.datetime.compare(v=vs.110).aspx.

```
int result = DateTime.Compare(date1, date2);
```